# Approve Actions not working by apex

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

In Salesforce.com apex class.

I'm trying to do a custom approve method:

```
List< ProcessInstanceWorkitem > listWork = [Select Id,ProcessInstanceId, OriginalActorId, CreatedDate, CreatedById,      ActorId  FROM ProcessInstanceWorkitem WHERE ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId =: obj.Id ORDER BY CreatedDate desc limit 1];

ProcessInstanceWorkitem lWorkItem;
lWorkItem = listWork[0];

Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
req.setComments( obj.Justificativa__c );
req.setAction('Approve');
req.setWorkitemId( lWorkItem.Id );
Approval.ProcessResult result =  Approval.process( req );
```

After invoke this method the record was approved BUT no one Approve Action was called.

Somebody knows why?

Answer (score -1):

You should use `ProcessSubmitRequest` class, instead of  `ProcessWorkitemRequest` class.